# Pulling Date from MySQL Database Remove Time

Tags: php, sql

I am pulling the value EventDate from a table called events. At the moment is giving me a timestamp along with the date -  2012-05-29 00:00:00.

Is there anyway to trim this in PHP?

Comment: Why not do it in MySQL already? Instead of `SELECT eventDate FROM events`, do `SELECT DATE(eventDate) FROM events`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using MySQL's build in functions such as [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) or even [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(EventDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS eventDate
FROM events;
```

```
SELECT
  DATE(EventDate) AS eventDate
FROM events;
```

Answer (score 8):

If don't want to store time stamp in DB,then change field type from datetime to date.Then while retrieving you will get only date.

OR

```
$date = //store DB date in this variable;
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to do this in PHP, use the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$date = '2012-05-29 00:00:00';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));  // 2012-05-29
```